Nonrestrictive attributive clauses, comma and meaning of the sentence
Here is a question:

Her first book introduced Detective Grand of Scotland Yard,  (___) institution, creativity  and perseverance help him to solve the most complicated cases.
A. where
B. when
C. which
D. whose

The answer seems to be D. whose. However it's hard for me to break down the structure according to accepted grammar.
Does 'whose institution, creativity  and perseverance help him to solve the most complicated cases.' stand as a nonrestrictive attributive clause?
If so, what is the coreference of 'whose' and what the relationship between 'whose', 'institution' and the following 'creativity  and perseverance...'?
And the comma after 'institution' really confuses me as a nonrestrictive attributive clauses. How to understand?
Or the answer may be incorrect? How to understand this sentence?

I can't make sense of pairing 'institution' with character traits. Do you mean 'intuition'? // Even 'Her first book introduced Detective Grand of Scotland Yard, which institution, along with Grand's creativity and perseverance, help him to solve the most complicated cases.' includes a strange juxtaposition.

Where's the question from? I suspect a typo.

Taking all three as character traits, ie with 'intuition, creativity, and perseverance, the correct choice is obviously whose.

Also possibly a typo for Grant? (Grand being an unusual surname.)

@EdwinAshworth Yeah that is a typo by double-check, thank you guys for pointing out. @'Kate Bunting' It is likely “The Daughter of Time,” comes the Grant. Thanks in advance, would you mind point me a direction to naming schema?

There is a twist. I'd say 'Detective Grand of Scotland Yard' is the complete attribution. so 'where' (referring to Scotland Yard) doesn't work. But 'Her first book introduced Detective Grand, based at Scotland Yard, where [his] institution, creativity and perseverance help him to solve the most complicated cases.' would be the obvious choice with 'based at Scotland Yard' a parenthetical.

@Edwin Ashworth
Thanks! Thanks for the alternative show case as example. Parenthetical is also the form I'm seeking to fill 'where' in the sentence. And that emphasize the assistance from institution (Scotland Yard), right?

It would be unusual to have '... Scotland Yard, where intuition, creativity and perseverance help him to solve ...' rather than say '... Scotland Yard, where the combined wealth of intuition and creativity (his own and co-workers')  help him to solve ...'.

I am in complete sympathy with your problem. It doesn't make much sense as stated. Given the context of the sentence I suspect a typo. I believe that "institution, creativity and perseverance " should be "intuition, creativity and perseverance". A less-likely, but still-possible replacement would be "intelligence, creativity and perseverance", but "intuition" seems a closer match to "institution".
Then, since all three terms are attributes of a person, D would be the obvious choice.

Thanks for the analysis, it is a typo. And intuition, creativity and perseverance here belongs to a person so we could not use 'which' as it's no meaning about 'belonging'?

@Fopopo - You got it.
